# If I have two (2) UIDatePickers and one (1) UIPickerView, do I need to use tags?

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, xcode4.5

I have an iPad app, built with XCode 4.5, Storyboards, ARC and iOS 6.  I have one controller with two UIDatePickers and one UIPickerView.  Since the UIDatePicker is derived from the UIPickerView, do I need to use tags to reference the UIPickerView in **numberOfRowsInComponent**?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm getting a clean build, but a run-time error before it even hits **numberOfRowsInComponent**  (set breakpoints; never gets there) of:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ClientSetupViewController
>   pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x8a89a10'

This is the code giving me the problem (manArray.Count = 6);

```
-(NSInteger)pvMan:(UIPickerView *)pvMan numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component  {

    return manArray.count;  //set number of rows
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's expecting

`-pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent`

instead of

`-pvMan:numberOfRowsInComponent`

Unless you have that defined somewhere else and that calls `-pvMan:numberOfRowsInComponent:`

Comment: Boy did I have that hosed up!  Finally got it straightened out and it works like a champ... thank you so much... I've been fighting this for 6 hours1

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that exception because you are not implementing `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:`. You have implemented `pvMan:numberOfRowsInComponent:`. Unfortunately for you, it doesn't matter if the `UIPickerView` `dataSource` implements `pvMan:numberOfRowsInComponent:`. It needs to be:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pvMan numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component  {
    return manArray.count;  //set number of rows
}
```

You do not need to differentiate between different pickers because you only have one `UIPickerView` for which you are the `dataSource`. Additionally, `UIDatePickers` subclass `UIControl`. `UIDatePicker` does have a `UIPickerView` private `ivar`, but since you are not (and would not ever be) its `dataSource`, this is of no concern to you.

Answer (score 0):

1) UIDatePicker IS NOT a subclass of UIPicker and as per Apple Docs, "Does NOT inherit from UIPickerView."

2) Consequently it DOES NOT Respond to `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent`. You set the rows on it by setting an NSDate object on it via the @Property `datePickerMode` with appropriate formats.

3) For the OTHER UIPickers you set the number of rows on them via the UIPickerViewDataSource protocol, and you must support:

```
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

and supply it with correct number of rows for the associated picker. How you associate the correct number of rows with the picker is by knowing which picker is asking at the time. You will do that by evaluating the `*pickerView` that is asking.